# Fix position of div

Tags: css, layout

This is a CSS / JQuery layout related question.

I have a layout composed by three stacked divs from top to bottom: header, main section and footer. Main section, has a tiny form inside.

[image]

The problem? My client want to keep that form "always" on screen, this way:

[image]

How can I get this done? I can´t figure out a way to accomplish this :(

**[This is the page currently online](http://goo.gl/rBMnDP)**

Thanks in adv,

Ariel

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: This is the current online page http://goo.gl/rBMnDP

Answer (score 2):

You can use fixed positioning:

```
<div id="fixed">
    this is a fixed DIV
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p>some text</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
#fixed 
{ 
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #313131;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Djbh9/)**